# Как правильно делать Резервное Копирование обычного ноутбука?

Tags: резервное-копирование

Я не программист.

1. какие программы (желательно бесплатные) можно скачать для резервного копирования
2. как правильно делать резервное копирование?
3. когда делаешь резервное копирование - все файлы сохраняются на внешний жесткий диск? или они как-то сжимаются?
4. внешний жёсткий диск должен быть подключен к ноутбуку 24 часа? (или перед завершением работы нужно нажать на кнопку "выполнить резервное копирование")
5. если что-то нужно восстановить - куда заходить и как выполнять восстановление какого-то файлах?

Процессор           Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4250U CPU @ 1.30GHz   1.90 GHz

Оперативная память  4,00 ГБ

Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Я использую [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) на загрузочной флешке. Для резервного копирования перезагружаю компьютер, подключаю внешний жесткий диск. Резервную копию делаю целиком для диска - все разделы и загрузочная запись. Резервная копия хранится в сжатом виде. Восстановить отдельные файлы так не получится, можно восстановить целиком образ на другой диск и извлечь нужные файлы. Работает для Windows и Linux. Это сложный путь для непрограммиста, ваша операционная система (которую вы не указали) точно предлагает более простой способ.

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за выделенное время на мой вопрос.
Операционную систему указал и заново сохранил.

Comment: Furkat Kasymov, если вы хотите, чтобы ваше  сообщение/комментарий получил Станислав, вам надо вместо `Станислав` написать `@StanislavVolodarskiy`

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что конкретно вы хотите получить. Может, вам будет достаточно тупо копировать файлы на внешнее хранилище через самый обычный проводник да и всё

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за выделенное время на мой вопрос. Операционную систему указал и заново сохранил.

Comment: всем спасибо за разъяснения и всяческую помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как правильно делать Резервное Копирование обычного ноутбука?

для начала стоит определиться хотя бы с уровнем навыков, нужными функциями резервирования и бюджетом который готовы слить на это.

> не программист

самые простые способы, не требующие каких то существенных знаний:

- скопировать нужные файлы на любой съемный накопитель встроенным проводником
- раскидать по частично бесплатным облакам(яндекс.диск, google drive и т.п.)
- раскидать по облакам, платящим тебе...) ну вроде ютуба и фотостоков :3 (для файлов созданных лично тобой, которыми не прочь поделиться - идеально)
- еще можно на старый ПК накатить **NAS**, или купить готовый(грубо говоря это личное облако)
- для файлов прочих типов то и дело плодятся всякие узкоспециализированные хосты\хабы\etc. хотите рисовать и где то хранить свои рисунки? есть фигма. пишите скрипты? есть github. схемы печатных плат? есть easyeda. ну и так далее...

для бытового применения, этих вариантов скорее всего хватит.

> 3. куда деваются, сжимаются ли

зависит от того какой вариант выберете. вариантов как софта так и железок - на любые: вкус, кошелёк и уровень паранои =)

> 4. должен ли быть подключен 24 часа

желательно наоборот, чтоб хотя бы резерв не сдох.

для наглядности: если скажем уроните ноут с балкона 10го этажа... всё что к нему подключено, так или иначе полетит вслед за ним с вполне очевидными последствиями :3

ну а для прокачки навыков, можно ознакомиться например с зоопарком `RAID`ов

инфы о них не мало, подробнее можете почитать хотя бы там:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID